# Extracting filename from html 'file' input: Chrome vs. Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload

I have an HTML form with an input field of the type 'file', with the id 'fdata'.
The input and file upload work perfectly on both Chrome and Firefox.

However, I also need to use the uploaded file's name in my javascript code, for another purpose. I used the following line:

```
var filename = $('#fdata').get(0).files[0].name;
```

Which works fine on Chrome, but it gives out the following error on Firefox:

```
TypeError: $(...).get(...).files[0] is undefined
```

This also failed when I used `$('#fdata')[0].files[0].name`... Am I doing it the wrong way? And if so, what is the right way..?

Comment: You say you have an input named `fdata` but then you use it with ID `fdata` ?  Please edit your post to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error appears when you try to access the file name before even selecting the file. 
You can avoid this by using

```
if($('#fdata').get(0).files.length){
    var filename = $('#fdata').get(0).files[0].name;
}else{
    alert("No file selected");
}
```

I tried reproducing the same on one of my existing code and got this, [image]

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so stupid.
My test case on Firefox was different than the one on Chrome, and indeed ran the function before I chose the file.
Thank you, and apologies for wasting your time!